# How do I keep my JFrame in front of everything else, but without my Java application ever having focus?

Tags: java, macos, swing, focus

I'm trying to write a customized on-screen keyboard (mac os x) for coders who can't use a physical keyboard. This involves a having a window stay on top of all open applications (this part is solved), but actually letting whatever application is immediately behind mine be the current active window. I am integrating with AppleScript System Events to handle the keystrokes, but the text is being sent to my application even though my Jframe is initialized as follows:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Programmer Keyboard");
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//components added here

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Can anyone advise me on this?
(To better understand what I'm looking for, open 'Keyboard Viewer.app')

Comment: I found a temporary workaround by triggering cmd+tab before the text is keystroked; but I would like a better solution, as this creates a flicker when the active window switches to my application and back.